# Angular Routing pass the controller to subitem of route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hello how can i pass same controller to the substate of main state that is loaded in other window?

```
.state('Project',{
    url:'/Project:projectId',
    views:{
        'mainContent':{
            templateUrl:'templates/view/project.html',
    controller:'ProjectCtrl'
        }
    }
}).state('Project.whoiscustomer',{
    url:'/whoiscustomer',
    views:{
        'rightContent':{
            templateUrl:'templates/projectMembers/whoiscustomer.html',
    controller:'ProjectCtrl'
        }
}
```

Could anyone explain this?

Or how to change this is project view propery?

```
ng-href="#/Project:projectId/whoiscustomer"
```

thouse are simple ionic ion-views ...

Comment: You want them to share the same controller instance?

Comment: Yes i do because its child loaded in left div and the project is main window..

Comment: Can you add your simplified templates to your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
.state('Project',{
    url:'/Project/:projectId',
    templateUrl:'templates/view/project.html',
    controller:'ProjectCtrl'
})
.state('Project.whoiscustomer',{
    url:'/whoiscustomer',
    templateUrl:'templates/projectMembers/whoiscustomer.html'
})
```

You don't have to name your views if you only have one, just use `<div ui-view></div>` in your templates.

Comment: I got 2 views one in another:)

Answer (score 0):

```
.state('Project',{
url:'/Project:projectId',
views:{
    'mainContent':{
        templateUrl:'templates/view/project.html',
controller:'ProjectCtrl'
    }
}
```

Adding   abstract: true,

make the trick

```
.state('Project',{
abstract: true,
url:'/Project:projectId',
views:{
    'mainContent':{
        templateUrl:'templates/view/project.html',
controller:'ProjectCtrl'
    }
}
```